# Unable to connect to postgresql through node/express; postgresql and node running in docker container

Tags: docker, express, node-postgres

Client (React), server (Node) and database(postgres) are all running in docker container. I am using npm package 'pg' to create pool and connect to the postgres database through express. However, I am not able to connect. Not able to run any query.

But I am able to connect the same postgres image through pgAdmin in my local machine. By connecting to port 5435.

I am new to docker and I am not able to figure out anything.
Help.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres_password
    ports:
      - '5435:5432'
  web-app:
    build:
      context: ./client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./client:/app
    ports:
      - '4001:3000'
    restart: on-failure
  to-do-api:
    build:
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
      - '5001:3001'
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./server:/app
    environment:
      - PGUSER=postgres
      - PGHOST=postgres
      - PGDATABASE=postgres
      - PGPASSWORD=postgres_password
      - PGPORT=5432
```

**index.js**

```
require('dotenv').config();

// Express App Setup
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const uuid = require('uuid/v4');

// Config
const config = require('./config');

// Initialization
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Postgres client
const { Pool, Client } = require('pg');

console.log('config.pgUser', config.pgUser);

const pool = new Pool({
  user: config.pgUser,
  host: config.pgHost,
  database: config.pgDatabase,
  password: config.pgPassword,
  port: config.pgPort,
  max : 20,
 
});

async function testConnection() {
  try {
   return await pool.query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS task"+
   "CREATE TABLE task (id serial PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(50), lastname VARCHAR(50));");
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
 }

async function main() {
  await testConnection();
}

main()
  .then (() => {
      console.error('Done');
      process.exit(0);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
      console.error('Error: %s', err);
      console.error('Error: %s', err.stack);
      process.exit(1);
  });

main();

pool.on('error', () => console.log('Lost Postgres connection'));



// Server
const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`));
```

Note: I am trying to connect to postgres running in docker container and create a table by running the query using node postgresql

Comment: You seem to have attached two images to the question; those aren't something I can run or search for to find more information.  Can you replace these with the text of your `docker-compose.yml` and the text of your source file, making sure to also include the actual text of your error message?

Comment: updated my question. I do not get any error in the console neither any table is created.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using one of the recent versions of the postgres npm dependency.

*You can set the pg npm package version 8.7.1 by adding `"pg": "8.7.1"` in depencecies object in package.json file in your express server folder.*

Answer (score 0):

There can be 2 possible reasons:

1. You need to pass the environment variables like: POSTGRES_DB, POSTGRES_USER and POSTGRES_PASSWORD in the docker compose file.
   For Example:

```html
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3.1'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    container_name: 'Postgresql'
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: admin
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
    volumes:
       - ./data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

2. Sometimes if you are working in windows you need to find you IPv4 Address address  using ipconfig command in CMD and replace it with localhost.

This worked for me.